# Extract values from XML file LOG

Tags: python

I am writing a script that extracts data from thousands of XML files and I can't seem to find a generical algorithm to solve the problem.

I need to extract the specific values of "Odometer", "Y", and "Z" contained in an XML file. The problem is that the string isn't always written in the same order, so I need a robust algorithm to get these values from each line from the LOG.

The XML file is structured as follow:

```
<Data>
  <Logs>
    <Log ID="1" Odometer="0" Speed="51.5" X=-"37.4791512" Y="-10.59835097" Z="220.42">
        <...>
    </Log>
    <Log ID="2" Odometer="1" Speed="42.5" X=-"37.4815122" Y="-10.58521075" Z="220.41">
        <...>
    </Log>
  </Logs>
</Data>
```

I already tried various approaches, but without sucess.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please include some of your various attempts that highlight an issue you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.